# What Happens to /dev/bus/usb After 1001 Connections

Tags: usb, usb-drive, usb-device, alpine-linux, lsusb

**/dev/bus/usb/*/*** lists all the usb devices connected on Alpine Linux. For example a phone could be **/dev/bus/usb/001/009**. When that phone is reconnected it will be **/dev/bus/usb/001/010**, i.e. it increments.

My question is what happens after 1001 connections?

```
/dev/bus/usb/001/009
                 010
                 ...
                 100
                 ...
                 500
                 ...
                 999
                 ???
```

Would the **???** go to 1000? Would it create a new folder say **003** under /dev/bus/usb/?

This is for manipulating the output of **usb-devices** and **lsusb**. Getting the Vendor and ProdID is not unique in my case.

I'd rather not plug in/out a usb cable 1000 times!

Comment: You could load and unload the kernel driver module for a usb hub, then you could probably try it out (in a loop).

Comment: ... or check here (or thereabouts): https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/usb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I read correctly https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/usb/core/hub.c#n2030 (code for a function called `choose_devnum`), it may wrap far earlier than that, at value 127 in fact, and then going back to 1:

```
    /* Try to allocate the next devnum beginning at
     * bus->devnum_next. */
    devnum = find_next_zero_bit(bus->devmap.devicemap, 128,
                    bus->devnum_next);
    if (devnum >= 128)
        devnum = find_next_zero_bit(bus->devmap.devicemap,
                        128, 1);
    bus->devnum_next = (devnum >= 127 ? 1 : devnum + 1);
```

And later on the `bus->devnum` property is really set only if `devnum` is less than 128.

Comment: Behaviour confirmed